How to recover Django users password after migrating project to a different server
I migrated my Django project to a different server, so I figured that the database is the most important thing on the server since my code is on GitHub and my media files on S3 bucket. So I made a backup of the database as an SQL dump.
I setup my project, restored the database, configure my domain etc. and everything seems like nothing changed (works well). Then I tried to login but it says incorrect password. I'm thinking the way Django hash the password has changed which makes it not match the hash on the database. Every  data on the database is  up to date.
How can I recover the password of the users and what are best practice methods to midrate successfully? I don't have access to the old server anymore.

Django hashes passwords, so normally you should not be able to recover it.

The main issue is the salt used to hash the password. To put simply, not possible.

But normally the way Django hashes should not matter (that much): a password contains both the hashing algo and the parameters (salt). These are stored in the password. So that means that even if the default hasher is changed, it still knows what hasher it used before.

I think the SECRET_KEY has change. Can that be the issue?

I just change the SECRET_KEY of my project and login works OK
